# StreamPlot "Part is not a Graphics primitive or directive."

Tags: graphics, units

I am trying to use StreamPlot with units. Here is a minimal example to produce the error "Part is not a Graphics primitive or directive." :

```
g[x_] := UnitSimplify[UnitConvert[x Quantity["Seconds"]]/Quantity["Seconds"]]
StreamPlot[{x, g[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

With this change it works:

```
g[x_] := UnitSimplify[x UnitConvert[Quantity["Seconds"]]/Quantity["Seconds"]]
StreamPlot[{x, g[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. I would report it to: "support@wolfram.com"